# Nano - insert content, save and exit

Tags: nano

I'm currently working on making a text file of the whole process of setting up my server for my normal usage.

And would like to know if there is any way to write a shell script so that I can make the "nano" insert content, save it, exit it, and then continue with the rest of my commands.

Cause when I put all of this into the shell script:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
ServerName localhost
sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

Then it shows the "nano" file editor with this content:

```
ServerName localhost
sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

Well, while I wanted it to save and exit after the `ServerName localhost`, so that my script could continue.

Would that be posibble anyhow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question. *SHH* doesn't exist, do you mean SH or SSH? Or maybe Bash? *(EDIT: brought an edit to fix this)*

Anyway, `nano` won't be much of assistance here. `echo` will.

```
echo "ServerName localhost" > /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

The above shell code will send your text into the file. Replacing `>` with `>>` will append it instead, if that's what you're looking for.

If you need root privileges to write to this file, then use `tee` instead of a simple shell redirection (`>`/`>>`). This will allow you to use `sudo` properly:

```
echo -e "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

`nano` is here so that you, the user, can write data manually into a file. However, if you're looking for an automated process, there's no need for an editor, coreutils can handle that just fine. Linux doesn't need the fancy `nano` interface to write into a file.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted using SSH. Thanks and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is not [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), this is shell programming, using `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith +1 for almost clairvoyant abilities.